# Update array in React JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays, react-native

I'm using react js. and working in class component. To understand the current scenario. I would like to tell you the what job this function is doing.

Well,
lets suppose i have shops array and week days array.

```
shop:[ {id:1,name:"S1"} ]

days = [ {id:1,name:"Monday"}, {id:2,name:"Tuesday"}, {id:3,name:"Wednesday"}, {id:4,name:"Thursday"}, ... ]
```

**Step 1:**

Now I selected first two days from **days** array and store them in a new array. lets call that array with **activeModalDays**

```
activeModalDays = [ {id:1,name:"Monday"}, {id:2,name:"Tuesday"} ],
```

**Step 2:**

Now we have a last array that will store the list of final form of objects that desire. lets call that

```
timingDetails = []
```

**Step 3**

Now create a function that maps activeModalDays and form object and returns that.

```
setTimeFunc =()=>{
    const timingDetails = this.state.activeModalDays.map((day) => {
        let start_time = this.state.start_time
        let close_time = this.state.close_time

        console.log("I'm in it 3",day.name)
        let obj = {
            shop:this.state.activePartition,
            day:day.name,
            start_time:start_time,
            close_time:close_time
        }

        let daytime= this.state.timingDetails.find((item)=>item.day===obj.day&&item.partition===obj.partition)
        console.log("din ",daytime)
        
        if (daytime) {
            let daytimeClone = {...daytime}
            console.log("deyare ",daytimeClone)
            console.log("true")

            if (start_time !==daytimeClone.start_time) {
            daytimeClone.start_time=start_time
            }
            if (close_time!==daytimeClone.close_time) {
            daytimeClone.close_time=close_time
            }    
            return daytimeClone
        } 
        else {
            return obj
        }

    })

    this.setState({ timingDetails: [...timingDetails] ,activeModalDays:[]});
}
```

At the end **timingDetails**  returns

```
[
{"close_time": 2022-09-06T11:14:09.926Z, "day": "Monday", "full_day": false, "shop": 1, "start_time": 2022-09-06T14:14:09.926Z},
 {"close_time": 2022-09-06T11:14:09.926Z, "day": "Tuesday", "full_day": false, "shop": 1, "start_time": 2022-09-06T14:14:09.926Z}
]
```

which is write output so far.
But Now when i repeat this process and new days like friday and saturday. The final objects of monday and tuesday removes automatically from **timingDetails**.

Comment: You need to take a clone first. Let me share the Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stack up on the `timingDetails` state, you should modify your `setState` like below

```
this.setState({ timingDetails: [...this.state.timingDetails,...timingDetails] ,activeModalDays:[]});
```

Or use the previous state of `timingDetails` in `setState`

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ timingDetails: [...prevState.timingDetails,...timingDetails] ,activeModalDays:[]}));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
etTimeFunc =()=>{

    const timingDetailsClone = [...this.state.timingDetails]


    const timingDetails = this.state.activeModalDays.map((day) => {

        let start_time = this.state.start_time
        let close_time = this.state.close_time

        console.log("I'm in it 3",day.name)
        let obj = {
            shop:this.state.activePartition,
            day:day.name,
            start_time:start_time,
            close_time:close_time
        }

        let daytime = timingDetailsClone.find((item)=>item.day===obj.day&&item.partition===obj.partition)
        console.log("din ",daytime)
        
        if (daytime) {
            let daytimeClone = {...daytime}
            console.log("deyare ",daytimeClone)
            console.log("true")

            if (start_time !==daytimeClone.start_time) {
            daytimeClone.start_time=start_time
            }
            if (close_time!==daytimeClone.close_time) {
            daytimeClone.close_time=close_time
            }    
            return daytimeClone
        } 
        else {
            return obj
        }

    })

    this.setState({ timingDetails: [...this.state.timingDetails,...timingDetailsClone,] ,activeModalDays:[]});
}
```

Comment: I am not able to test this code due to incompleted code.

Comment: It's oky kaushik. I'm glad you replied and spend your previous time in read and replying my question. I put your code as it is. It didn't returned any error but it behavior was same as it was before. But as you said you had not full code so didn;t tested. This things still makes you an amazing programmer. I appreciate brother.